# Does the Metamagic Adept feat gives access to Flexible Casting as well or just sorcery points when taken at 1st level as a Variant Human Sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, sorcerer, metamagic

## Build

Race: Variant Human (feat: Metamagic Adept)

Class: Sorcerer (Shadow)

Metamagic adept feat:

> (...)You gain 2 sorcery points to spend on Metamagic (*these points are added to any sorcery points you have from another source but can be used only on Metamagic*). You regain all spent sorcery points when you finish a long rest.

So I gain 2 sorcery points that I can use only on metamagic.

Examples: Subtle spell 2 times or Quickened spell one time.

Then after doing that: my sorcery points are now at 0

Can I then use spell points (or spell slots if you don't use this variant) to simply regain 1-2 sorcery points?

##### Sidenote

Just by curiosity, if the above is allowed and there are other uses because of a racial ability or variant somewhere, can the newly acquired sorcery points be used for anything else than metamagic? (I'm assuming there might be such an ability somewhere)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, as I think it has been asked before, albeit in a slightly different context. The answer I gave to the linked question definitely answers this question, but if other users insist on this question being open, I will gladly copy and paste it here. Let us know if the linked question solves your problem or not.

Comment: I couldn't find it but thank you one of the answer mentions: **Metamagic Adept does not give the Flexible Casting feature.**  I really tried like 5 times to find it by search, so can something be done to make it easier to find?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised you didn't find that since it's asked in the context of a non-sorcerer taking the feat. Fortunately, we can do something about that! When we close a question as a duplicate, it serves to make the answer easier to find. Now, when someone has the same question, they are twice as likely to find their answer thanks to your post here.

Comment: Awesome! at least it's gonna be useful